# Android TextView doesn't update its text when textIsSelectable is set to true

Tags: android, textview

I faced this strange problem that caused me a lot of headache and trouble.

I published an application that is a repository of several books, I decided to use TextView to display the text of each chapter because it fits the requirements and it is fast and easy to be used.

The user asked that he could select a text and copy it, I used textIsSelectable = true and everything was fine, next day he called me to report that the text in not changing, you open a chapter and you switch to another chapter but the text remains the same.

I thought it might be some logical problem from my side, but after some debugging the problem was in TextView, when I set textIsSelectable = false; everything was fine.

To be sure I used a static int that is increased each time the text is displayed, the text remained unchanged.

So what is the problem? am I using TextView the wrong way? or it is some bug in the TextView itself?

Here's my layout (txtBody is the TextView that causes the problem)

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@android:color/white">

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            >

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="right">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Title Text"
                    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="right"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Detail Text"
                    android:id="@+id/txtBody"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
                    android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>


</FrameLayout>
```

I use this code to set the text:

```
String body = MainDataManager.getInstance().getChapterBody(book.getTable(), chapter.getId());
    updateTextStyle();
    txtTitle.setText(chapter.getTitle());
    txtBody.setText(body, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: After 2~3 hours of experimenting, I have found this was the cause. I hate when my time is wasted like this.... For my Google search this page was the first hit and the second hit was [https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78491] The description exactly matches my case. It was marked as a BUG in 2014 with medium priority, and it has not been fixed YET in 2016. This is not the first time I wasted my time like this... by a bug that has not been fixed for over few years.

Answer (score 0):

Uase invalidate() method before you change text of textview.

```
 String body = MainDataManager.getInstance().getChapterBody(book.getTable(), chapter.getId());
    updateTextStyle();
    txtTitle.invalidate();
    txtTitle.setText(chapter.getTitle());
    txtBody.invalidate();
    txtBody.setText(body, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: However I had to do invalidate in the activity OnStart() or OnResume() methods.